# How to get Editable Tableview Cell value after edit complete in JavaFX FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have a TableView `selectedProductsTable` with editable column `quantityColumn`.
I want to take value after user edit column. method gets called without problem but I don't how to get the value.

```
@FXML
private TableView selectedProductsTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn quantityColumn;
.......

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   selectedProductDataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   quantityColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
}

@FXML
public void onEditCommitSelectedProductTable( ){

    // this method fires when user press enter after finish editing "Quantity" column value.

    // how to get Edited value


}
```

I'm adding values to the table in method which get called in button click.
[image of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qASq6.png)

Comment: Can you show the relevant FXML? What event is `onEditCancelSelectedProductTable` associated with?

Comment: method name should be 'onEditCommitSelectedProductTable( )' which fire on 'Quantity' column 'on Edit Commit' event. still do you need FXML code ?

Comment: Just add the FXML declaration of the quantity column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`onEditCommit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#onEditCommitProperty) handler takes a [`CellEditEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellEditEvent.html) object as its parameter, which contains information about the event, including the new value. So you can do

```
@FXML
public void onEditCommitSelectedProductTable(CellEditEvent<?,?> event){
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    // other data that might be helpful:
    TablePosition<?,?> position = event.getTablePosition();
    int row = position.getRow();
    // etc ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks... 
one other thing, if user forget to  press Enter exception occurs. is there any way to handle it. Is there any way to exit from editable mode if user forget to press Enter.

Comment: By default it should cancel the edit if the user moves focus somewhere else without pressing enter. Where is the exception being thrown?